# Chirping Whine in USB Audio Interface

Tags: usb, behringer, whistling

I’ve got an issue and I can’t really pinpoint it despite the search terms of USB audio whine giving me plenty of ideas up to this point.

I’ve got a Behringer U-Phoria UMC22 and a connected Rode NTG3 - this issue is I’ve got a chirping noise in the Audio. Sometimes.

Audio samples:
1: https://www.dropbox.com/s/6zm1w24ytabnj9l/stoerungen.m4a?dl=0
2: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x183gm2g9dczkko/stoerungen2.m4a?dl=0

Disconnect the Microphone -> No noise present
Connect Microphone without XLR Cable -> Noise present
Using different USB Cable -> Noise present
USB Cable directly to Mac Studio -> Noise present
USB Cable to USB C Hub to Macbook -> Noise present
Disconnected basically everything electrical in my apartment -> Noise present.
Connect Microphone to Elgato Wave XLR -> Noise present

I’ve put ferrit cores on all cables.

Due to the fact that there is no noise with the microphone on another interface I guess the microphone is ok. The cables should probably be ok too as it’s with multiple different cables. PCs too. So it’s the interface itself that has the issues so I was thinking about maybe an issue with the amplifier but the noise sounds a lot like a signal interference, it seems to have patterns and it’s only present sometimes.

Any ideas? Have you heard a signal like that before and can give me a hint on what type of signal could cause this interference and what to check?

I’m planning on removing the interface from the setup soon and testing the interface at another location to check if it’s the interface itself or if it’s the surrounding electronics interfering like I’m suspecting.

Comment: If you look in the Related sidebar to the right, you will see this type of fault is not uncommon. Sounds like you are checking the right things to identify the component or area that is at fault.

Comment: Sadly none of those answers do relate. I tested a lot more in the meantime and even measured EMF fields but it’s unclear where the chirping is coming from.

Comment: It’s most probably a defective microphone by this point as I even galvanically separated the interface on the USB Bus from the Mac and the Noise is still happening.